# C# app that will stay in the background and receive commands via cmd arguments?

Tags: c#, process, cmd, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to make an app in Visual Studio with C# that will stay in the background and then other programs could start the app with just one argument and it will popup a notification (another form) with that argument.

I need the app to be consisted of just one process, i don't need multiple processes/instances of my app. I just want it to stay in the background and when someone starts the app with an argument, for example `MyApp.exe` "this is a notification", it will just pop up another form that will have that cmd argument in it, and it won't start the app as another process.

I hope you get my point, if you don't I can explain it more.

Comment: have you though about using WCF in your application to listen for messages from other applications?

Answer (score 2):

What you are wanting is more of a job for a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). A Windows Service is a program, with no GUI interface, that sits in the background and does something. The service is usually started when the computer boots up and stays running till the computer shuts down.

Communication between other programs and you service can be done using [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (or WCF). WCF allows communication between two applications using one or more [transports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx).

Without using WCF, another way (although arguably less efficient) to "communicate" is through a database. Your service can monitor a table for rows added and your main program can add these rows whenever something needs to happen. The choice comes down to really what your end goal is.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [named pipes](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/dotnet-35-adds-named-pipes-support) (System.IO.Pipes)
or WCF's [`System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx).
Other options are: old .NET Remoting or TCP/IP Sockets.

The 'background app' can be an Windows Service, but it won't allow showing any GUI form to the user, as background services don't have any forms.

For an easy way to create Windows "Background" Services see [OpenSource TopShelf project](http://topshelf-project.com/).